# Draw an image in Unity onGui

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I draw an image inside `onGui` function in Unity? I am using the following code in order to draw some `textField`. However how can I draw an image in a box?

```
GUI.TextField (new Rect (0, 0, 60, 30), counter.ToString());
GUI.TextField (new Rect (60, 0, 60, 30), max.ToString());
GUI.TextField (new Rect (120, 0, 60, 30), value.ToString());
```

I have tried to user the following code:

```
Texture2D image = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("12.jpeg");
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(200, 200, image.width, image.height), image);
```

I got null reference error. Is the above code correct? Am I missing just the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a box but draw it before other GUI elements that should appears above the image because OnGUI draws in the same order that you codes, if you put your box after your text inputs, for example, they will be drawn behind the box ;)

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(200, 200, image.width, image.height), image);
```

**edited:** Just to be clear, DrawTexture expect a Texture not a Texture2D this is, probably, your problem at this time.

**edited:**

Didn't see your null reference exception at first. Try to change your code to load your image on Start() instead of OnGUI() because OnGUI runs many times per frame and also use `image = Resources.Load("12.jpg") as Texture2D` (or as Texture if you want to maintain DrawTexture instead of Box).

Remenber that Resources.Load() will search under Assets/Resources/ so your 12.jpg needs to be under this reserved folder named "Resources" (capitalized). If it is under sub folders I think you need to specify it in your path like `Resources.Load("sub/12.jpg")`.

Comment: Therefore, how can I draw an image ongui ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the null reference. Without log is complicated to define why you are getting null reference. It may be because your 12.jpg is not under a "Resources" folder at your assets (in fact that whay you are calling it need to be right at "Assets/Resources/12.jpg") and should not be at OnGUI because it will be loaded many times per frame...

Comment: I didn't have any resources folder. Is it necessary to create one? In fact I create a folder Resources under Assets folder but zip, I got again  SystemNullReferenceException

Comment: Yes you need to create one. Resources class search into this unity reserved folder only and it needs to be capitalized and not compressed. See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html and http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder for more details...

Comment: I put it in Assets/Resources/12.jpg but I got null ref again.

Comment: So please edit your question with your console log to be easily to understand where is your null reference.

Comment: Also you can declare your Texture 2D as public and just use inspector to define 12.jpg to it. Everyting you put under Resources folder will be compiled with your final game even if you don't use it so you need to use it wisely, In my opinion this is not a case to use Resources.Load().